# wpf app and external processes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading

I've wrote an wpf app, from which i would like to call 20 external processes, after all processes are finished wpf app should continue normal execution.
I succeded in calling those processes and they work just fine. They receive parameters from wpf, but afterwards wpf gui is not showing and qouted message is showed in console.

When I call process from the following code once or twice it works well, but after few times it stops working. I already tried commented lines

```
 string arguments = "thumbnail " + input + " " + output.LocalPath;

 Process p = Process.Start(videoToolPath, arguments);
 while(!p.HasExited)
 {
       Thread.Sleep(1000);
 }
 //p.Dispose();
 //p.Kill();
 //p.Close();
```

Console:

```
'VJProject.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: VJProject.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'VJProject.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: VJProject.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'VJProject.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: VJProject.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'VJProject.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: VJProject.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'VJProject.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: VJProject.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'VJProject.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: VJProject.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'VJProject.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: VJProject.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'VJProject.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: VJProject.vshost.exe): Loaded 'E:\Projects\MediaGUI\newVSProject\VJProject\VJProject\bin\Debug\VJProject.vshost.exe'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'VJProject.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: VJProject.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'VJProject.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: VJProject.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'VJProject.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: VJProject.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'VJProject.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: VJProject.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'VJProject.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: VJProject.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'VJProject.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: VJProject.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'VJProject.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: VJProject.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xaml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xaml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'VJProject.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: VJProject.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\WindowsBase\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\WindowsBase.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'VJProject.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: VJProject.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\PresentationCore\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationCore.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'VJProject.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: VJProject.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The thread 0x1ee4 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x1e18 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
'VJProject.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: VJProject.vshost.exe): Loaded 'E:\Projects\MediaGUI\newVSProject\VJProject\VJProject\bin\Debug\VJProject.exe'. Symbols loaded.
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'VJProject.App..ctor'
'VJProject.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: VJProject.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'VJProject.App.Main'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'VJProject.App.InitializeComponent'
The thread 0x26d8 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
'VJProject.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: VJProject.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework.Aero2\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.Aero2.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'VJProject.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: VJProject.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework-SystemXml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\PresentationFramework-SystemXml.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'VJProject.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: VJProject.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework-SystemXmlLinq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\PresentationFramework-SystemXmlLinq.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'VJProject.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: VJProject.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\UIAutomationTypes\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\UIAutomationTypes.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
```

Comment: Do not call Thread.Sleep in the UI thread. It will disable your UI. Instead of actively waiting for the HasExited property, add a handler for the [Process.Exited](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

Comment: "it stops working" is not really a helpful description. How can we tell you what the problem is if we do not know anything about what your WPF program and your other processes are doing... On another note, the output of the debugger console is just "normal" stuff and not related to your problem. It shows the (system) libaries used in your project being loaded and that you did some "Step into" actions in the debugger...

Comment: Try to localize the problem area. There are different ways to do it. One (simple) way could be to create a small console test application project and duplicate your code related to running the processes there - emulate the runtime behavior as accurately as possible. If the WPF app is able to execute processes concurrently - do the same in the console test app. Thus you should be able to find out whether your problem is related to how you run the processes. If the console test app does not reveal any issues, then look at how your WPF app consumes any output data of those processes you execute

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to wait for the external program to exit:

```
var process = Process.Start(...);
process.WaitForExit();

int code = process.ExitCode;
if (code != 0)
{
   //failure
}
else
{
   //success
}
```

(Don't do this inside your UI-Thread, it will block it)

Answer (score 1):

You want to do this asynchronously. The easiest way to do this is with the `async` `await` pattern. The bad news is that `Process` does not support Task async.

```
public Task ProcessVideo(string input, xxx output)
{
    string arguments = "thumbnail " + input + " " + output.LocalPath;

    Process p = Process.Start(videoToolPath, arguments);
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    p.Exited += (o, e) => 
    {
        if(p.ExitCode == 0)
        {
            tcs.SetResult(null);
        }
        else
        {
            tcs.SetException(someException);
        }
        p.Dispose();
    }
    return tcs.Task;
}

//Then call it by 

var listOfFilesToProcess = new List<string>(){ ... };
await Task.WhenAll(listOfFilesToProcess.Select(file => ProcessVideo(file, output));
```